# Facebook-Heroku hosting limitations?

Tags: php, facebook, heroku, hosting

What are the heroku system limitations for their "free" php hosting packages ... like disk space , memory usage ?

Comment: Yeah, this has no place on SO. It's clearly a question for their sales department.

Comment: Not sure about Heroku, but Orchestra offers a free package that allows a single concurrent connection at a time, and you have to use a subdomain like http://yoursite.orchestra.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Radoslav i could not find a readable price chart so i would suggest contacting Support.  if you could post back with the info you get, as i would like to know myself but i do not have an account.

Pricing http://www.heroku.com/

Comment: General pricing here: http://www.heroku.com/pricing#0-0 - i'm unsure what the specifics are of the free setup arrangement with Facebook though

Comment: Thanks igy, we already found that, just wanted a specs table for that package.

Comment: Already contacted them and got explanation how to add more "dynos" ... so my question is more pointed to someone already using them , in my case I got only paypal , and will be surpriced "bad" if my app with heroku is down or got teribble performance